# Copy url with screenshot

Tags: windows, screenshot, url

I am currently using the 'Print Screen' function to take screenshots of several Webpages and add them together to one Word document. To do this, I open my Webpage, 'Print Screen', go to my Word document, paste my screenshot, go back to my Webpage, copy the URL, go to my Word document, paste my URL under the screenshot. I do that for each screenshot I take, adding the screenshots one under the other.

I am looking for a program that will allow me to do this without having to go back and forth between my Word document and my Webpage. I tried Greenshot which works great to take a screenshot and add it to a Word document without having to flip between the Webpage and the Word document. But I still need to go back to my webpage to copy the URL and then paste it into my Word document. Is there a software which can copy both the screenshot and the URL together?

Feature requirements:

1. Copy URL when take a screenshot.
2. Screenshot and URL can be saved together in Word or Excel (or any other editable format). The aim is not to share online and I need to save both the screenshot and URL together, not just one or the other.
3. Need to be able to add several screenshots and URL in the one file so that it can be reviewed together.
4. Compatible with Windows.
5. Free or Cheap.
6. Not a video – I need to be able to review the document quickly.

Comment: What OS? What price? Read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and [edit] your question.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Currently your question can't be answered because the questions @JanDoggen asked are open. Please add the relevant information. Have a nice stay.

Comment: The question could be reopened. The OP added all necessary information

Comment: Evernote will do this.

Answer (score 3):

From PDFforge.org, get PDFCreator and install, yes you will have a screen capture in the end.

[image]

Configure **Page Setup** in this way, or change it later after you test it.

Goto website and print to PDFcreator, you can make PDFCreator the default printer temporarily.

[image: PDFCreator options]

After save you have a PNG, but you also select TIF or JPG formats.  After you have done this to a number of websites.  Drag and drop all of them into MS word at once. You can add a 01,02,03 to the beginning of the filename and it **should** **hopefully** insert them in that order.  If the URL is too long it may truncate.

Comment: Interesting approach! But should work

Answer (score 1):

I've searched a little, and haven't found any perfect matches, but there seems to be some alternative roads you could try.

### Automatic screenshot of multiple pages

Tools like [Grab them all](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-them-all/) or similar, to capture a list of web pages, and store the images in one (or several) folders with a converted URL as the filename.

This could possibly be extended with a tool to convert a folder with images into a document, where the image and the filename are included.

### Screenshot with annotations

Tools like [qSnap](//qsnapnet.com/) (available for multiple browsers) makes screenshot of any given web page, and opens it up for annotation within the browser.

This allows for you opening up all the web pages in your browser, make the captures, and then make annotations using the URL as the text (copied from the address bar).

### Create capture documents

Previously I used [SnagIt](//www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) for making screenshots of any kind, and it can save the captures with extra information, and you can work on the captures in groups. In addition a capture can contain the original URL (or source URL) as part of the capture (see [Where do I find the original URL of my web captures in Snagit 12?](https://feedback.techsmith.com/techsmith/topics/snagit_12_tag_url)). Not sure if it can capture a list of URLs though.

This allows for you to keep the captured web pages in a set for review purposes, and you can rather easily get the source URL. SnagIt also has loads of annotation and editing possibilities.